# bookdown: ! LaTeX Error: Environment Shaded undefined

Tags: r, undefined, bookdown

My code is [here](https://github.com/bubifengyun/deepin-bible)
I change latex class to sjtu.cls.

when in *deepin-bible*, `make`, it will pop error, like

Rscript --quiet _render.R "bookdown::pdf_book"
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'pdf' failed
! LaTeX Error: Environment Shaded undefined.

错误: Failed to compile deepin-bible.tex. See deepin-bible.log for more info.
停止执行
错误: Failed to compile the book to bookdown::pdf_book
停止执行
make: *** [pdf] Error 1

Exited with status 2.

I find that `Shaded` had defined in *latex/preamble.tex*, and I also move all code in preamble.tex to template.tex, it pops the same error.
Can anyone help me? thank you.

Comment: I had solved. Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your solution as an answer? That would make this question useful to future readers.

Comment: Yes, as we all know that, https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese, can work well. I change the latex class to SJTUThesis.cls. Modify template.tex and preamble.tex. Pops this error. I recover to original tex. every time, I delete one block, then I find that, some block cannot be removed. So this problem was solved. I don't know the real reason. Just try and try.

Comment: This is my codee, sahre in https://github.com/bubifengyun/SJTUThesis-Rmd